# Install ocfs on Fedora

Tags: fedora, ocfs2

I am not able to install ocfs2-tools on Fedora OS. According to google this should be enough: yum install -y ocfs2-tools (it says: cannot find the package).I Tried: yum install ocfs2-tools.x86_64.I Tried: yum list available | grep -l 'ocfs' (there is no such package). On ubuntu it should be: apt-get install ocfs2tools. 
How can I install ocf2 tool on Fedora distribution ?

edited:
I downloaded ocfs2-tools-e797cf5f27e9d4238efe27fa2203b102e44246f6.tar.gz from fedora git. Installed "Development tools". I tried to run ./configure script, but I got message: "Unable to find com_err library" so I installed e2fsprogs-devel and after I tried to run configure script I got message: "Unable to find uuid library" so I installed libuuid and libblkid-devel and I got message: "Unable to find ncurses library" ... help :)

Answer (score 1):

ocfs2-tools package is no longer shipped in fedora repository since Fedora 16:

> This package was retired on 2011-07-25 due to it being unable to build
>   this package for multiple releases (FTBFS)

See [this commit in dist git](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/ocfs2-tools.git/commit/?id=e797cf5f27e9d4238efe27fa2203b102e44246f6).

So it looks like building this package yourself would require more effort icluding patching the sources.

If you really like to dig deeper, good start would be (on a fedora machine):

```
fedpkg clone --anonymous ocfs2-tools
cd ocfs2-tools
fedpkg switch-branch f15
```

So that now you have everything (spec file, patches) needed to build the package for Fedora 15 (the last version):

```
$ ls 
minor_build_fixes.diff  no_stonithd.diff  o2cb_pcmk.diff  ocfs2-tools.spec  sources
```

Now you can try to install build dependencies (`yum-builddep ocfs2-tools.spec` executed under root) and try to build it, check the errors and fix all the problems ...